# Cannot delete my own comment due to latex formatting?

Tags: support, mathjax, comment

Sorry if this is not the proper place to ask this question, but I cannot find related information from the help pages.

I wrote a comment on [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1195409/permutations-to-satisfy-a-challenging-restriction/1197057) giving some extended and related data to help analyzing the question. Due to the large amount of numbers appeared as a sequence, I used \$ signs to quote the whole sequence of numbers. As a result, the comment (and all the previous comments under the same answer) has widened and part of the comments cannot be shown (they seem to be outside the webpage margin). Worse still, the delete button for the comment cannot be shown either, probably outside the margin as well. Is there any admin that I can ask for deleting that single comment? The comment is the one starting with $P_1(12)$. Thank you very much!

Comment: I edited it a bit. Does it look better now? Long LaTeX strings in comments give the parser a headache. Splitting them helps (when possible).

Comment: See [Comments layout break if Math expression is too long](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2652/comments-layout-break-if-math-expression-is-too-long). (And maybe some other posts linked there.)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes it is ok now. Thank you!

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks, I learn a lot from the post.

Comment: If you're familiar with the CSS debugger of your browser (Inspect object in FF) you can delete the node of the MathJax that breaks formatting, then either edit or delete as needed.

Comment: Yeah, there's a bug that hit me once, too. Best thing to do in these cases is flag it for moderation, and nag someone to fix the problem in general.

Comment: Also: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/13700/should-i-flag-comments-where-long-mathjax-breaks-page-layout

Comment: If I recall correctly, you need white space every 8x characters or so. MathJax for whatever reason does not like very long expressions without some sort of white space.

Comment: @CameronWilliams It's not MathJax; it's SE who don't like long text in comments without whitespace. So they insert some automatically, breaking the formulas on such occasions.

Comment: @Woodface Oh, yeah you're right. Thanks for the correction.